# How do I get the value OUT of my maybe<> monad?

Tags: c++, monads

For educational reasons, I'm trying to implement a maybe monad in C++14. My (perhaps overly simplistic) understanding of monads is that they let you define a computation as a series of composable function calls. The wikipedia article on monads calls them "programmable semicolons" because they let you define what happens between what would otherwise be a set of discreet function calls. The maybe monad is a monad that interrupts computation if a failure occurs.

```
template<class T>
struct maybe
{
    maybe( const T& t ) : argument( t ), valid( true ) {}
    maybe() : argument(), valid( false ) {}

    T argument;
    bool valid;
};

template<class T>
maybe<T> just( const T& t ) { return maybe<T>(t); }

template<class T>
maybe<T> nothing() { return maybe<T>(); }

auto terminal_maybe = [] ( auto term ) {
    return [=] ( auto func ) {
        return func( term );
    };
};

auto fmap_maybe = [] ( auto f ) {
    return [=] ( auto t ) {
        if( t.valid ) {
            try {
                t.argument = f( t.argument );
                printf("argument = %d\n",t.argument);
            }
            catch(...) {
                t.valid = false;
            }
        }

        return (t.valid) ? terminal_maybe( just( t.argument ) ) : terminal_maybe( nothing<decltype(t.argument)>() );
    };
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    auto plus_2 = [] ( auto arg ) { return arg + 2; };
    auto minus_2 = [] ( auto arg ) { return arg - 2; };

    maybe<int> forty = just(40);

    terminal_maybe(forty)
        (fmap_maybe( plus_2 ))
        (fmap_maybe( plus_2 ));

    printf("result = %d\n",forty.argument);

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see I am super close! I can chain multiple calls together monadically (and I can tell from printf that my value does what I expect (increments from 40 to 42 and then from 42 to 44)). The problem is that I have no way to get the final value OUT! I tried making terminal_maybe accept a reference (auto&) and that forced me to modify fmap's return statement (to just return terminal_maybe( t ) rather than a new maybe). But it still didn't have the correct value for the final printf.

Comment: You may want to develop what's missing for those that can do C++ but have no idea what a "maybe monad" is.

Comment: Thanks ! At first glance, shouldn't the functor returned by `fmap_maybe` take `t` by reference ?

Comment: `fmap_maybe` creates a new `terminal_maybe` instead of mutating the one you passed in, therefore the original value of `t` (`forty`) will not change. Put the result of the whole `fmap_maybe` sequence into a variable, then use an "unwrapper" function to get the value out of it. Quick and dirty example: http://ideone.com/DaCiA2

Comment: @DCoder well that comforts me then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works, but I don't know if it makes sense from a FP point of view.

```
auto unwrap = [](auto const &f) {
    return f;
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    auto plus_2 = [] ( auto arg ) { return arg + 2; };
    auto minus_2 = [] ( auto arg ) { return arg - 2; };

    maybe<int> forty = just(40);

    auto const &outv = terminal_maybe(forty)
        (fmap_maybe( plus_2 ))
        (fmap_maybe( plus_2 ))
        (unwrap);

    std::printf("result = %d\n",outv.argument);

    return 0;
}
```